# Column displays source table.column name

Tags: ms-access

Access sometimes makes queries display the column name as `table_name.column` name.

For example the source table name is `rpt11a_valuation_program` and the column name is `Product_symbol`, Access displays this as `rpt11a_valuation_program.Product_symbol` rather than just `Product_Symbol`

[image: Microsoft Access column]

Comment: sorry, what was the question..?

Answer (score 1):

If same field name exist in both tables then access by default will show TableName.FieldName in query results to avoid confusion and uniqueness. You can rename the field to more meaningful name with As keyword.Please note that both field cannot have same name.